# How to get Delphi to access an SQLite database in the directory of the executable?

Tags: sqlite, delphi

I am using SQLite, rather than MySQL, because it is simpler and requires no extra running software, just my executable.

For simplicity's sake I would prefer to have the database file in the same directory as my executable, ***and*** to be able to copy or move that folder elsewhere and still have the program work. Meaning that it can find the SQLite database file, which was copied along with it, in its new location.

However, it looks like I have to specify an absolute path to the database file.

Is there any way to change this at run time?

For those who don't quite follow that, I will try to explain:

- let us say that my app's .exe is in `C:\A\A.exe`
- so, I want to put the database file in the same directory. Lets call it `C:\A\A.db`
- Delphi ***seems to*** require an absolute path. I.e, `C:A\A.db` and not `.\A.db`
- I want to be able to copy both the .exe and its database to `C:\B` and still have the .exe be able to find its database file, which is now in `C:\B\A.db`

How can I do that programmatically, at run-time?

## Answer

The path to the database is stored in the database connection component, so something like `myConnection.parameters.database := 'C:\my_database.db;`

Comment: In windows the database should be in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\<MyCompany>\<MyApp>`

Comment: That tells me where to find it - by default. I want to copy/move and still have the .exe find it in the same directory as the .exe

Comment: You are looking for ParamStr(0)

Comment: That tells me how to find the .EXE. How do I then use that value to locate the Sqlite database?

Comment: use ExtractFilePath ?

Comment: You say you have the SQLlite db in the same folder as the executable, not? Maybe the question is unclear at the moment?

Comment: Do you want to locate the db and move it to the EXE folder?

Comment: Yes, I do (+1). PLUS, it both are copied or moved again, the .exe should always be able to find the database in its current directory.

Comment: I wan it always to be in the same directory as the .exe.  So, how do I code it to get the connection directory to be `.` which is the program's directory?

Comment: I still do not understand which specific directory you are searching. Do you want to seach for the DB file *anywhere* on the disk? Please provide a specific example of the copying/moving, and what exaclty you want your program to do afterwards.

Comment: `.` is the working directory. That is not necessarily the directory where the executable is.

Answer (score 4):

Just compute the SQlite3 database file name on the fly, using:

```
myDbFileName := ExtractFilePath(paramstr(0)) + 'mysqlite3file.db3';
```

This will point e.g. to `c:\my\app\folder\mysqlite3file.db3` file, when you run `c:\my\app\folder\myprogam.exe`.

Comment: I can ***find*** it easily enough - I just don't know how to ***set*** it in my code. It must be a property of the connection or datasource or ...

Comment: @Mawg AFAIR the database file is just the database name for SQLite3.

Answer (score 1):

First you want to copy the db to the EXE folder :

```
if FileExists(FDConnection1.Params.Database) then
CopyFile(Pchar(FDConnection1.Params.Database),Pchar('EXE Folder\A.db'),True);
```

then you can change the connection to the new db (copy) :

```
if FileExists('EXE Folder\A.db') then
begin
  FDConnection1.Params.Database := 'EXE Folder\A.db';
  FDConnection1.Connected := True;
end;
```

Comment: I don't think copying a file is what OP wanted. I understood the question, and the comments, as wanting to know how to access the DB via relative path.

Comment: I think he say :  I want to put the database file in the same directory. Lets call it C:\A\A.db

Answer (score 1):

You always have to specify absolute path to the database file. Alternative would be preforming a full search for the database file which is stupid.
Here is a little piece of code I use to create backup of the database so you get the idea:

```
procedure TForm1.dxBarButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var fileSource, fileDest,dirName: string;
 begin
 dirname := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\backup database' ;
 if not directoryexists(dirName) then
 CreateDir(dirName);

 if MessageDlg('Create database copy ?'+ #13#10 +'Attention,new copy will overwrite existing one',
    mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0, mbYes) = mrNo then
    exit
    else
  try
  dataModule2.ACRDatabase1.Close;  
  fileSource := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'sgit.adb';
  fileDest := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\backup database\sgit.adb';
  If CopyFile(PChar(fileSource), PChar(fileDest), False) then begin
     dataModule2.ACRDatabase1.Open;
     dataModule2.FIRME.Open;
     ShowMessage('Copy was made !');
  end  else
     RaiseLastOSError;
  except  on E: Exception do
     showMessage(Format('Error during copying : %s',[E.Message]));
  end;
end;
```

So in your case you can write to an *.ini file where the database was copied to and then load the information during startup of your application. So basically you must always supply the database path (fileSource). How you do it is up to you. Just an idea ...